# Is the perceived flexibility in this picture (when moving it) related to the perceived curvature when it's not moving?

Tags: perception, vision, optical-illusion

Look at this picture:

[image: [![enter image description here][2]][2]ook]

All squares are of equal size but when you look at the picture the horizontal and vertical bands they constitute seem to be curved. When you move the picture up and down the horizontal bands seem to get flexible. The same holds for the horizontal direction.
Is this perception of flexibility related to the perception of curvature?

Maybe someone can make it move up and down instead of making it move up and down (or from the left to the right and vice-versa) by using the mouse or pad.

Comment: I think the middle illusion is an entirely different effect. In fact, your question implicitly asks for the difficult-to-investigate question whether all three illusions are based on the same neural correlate. As a consequence, this question is in my opinion too broad, as one needs to investigate what neural correlates underlie each illusion, before the answerer can proceed to the question what mechanisms the three have in common and do those common correlates explain the effect of physical motion on the illusionary motion effect?

Comment: @AliceD I don't know if the effects have the same neural correlates as those of the illusions without moving them. Maybe that's the question.

Comment: It's best to ask explicit questions - for instance, it's best to wrap up a post with a one-liner that abstracts the question proper. '*Maybe that's the question*' indicates you don't know what you really want to know. If you don't know the question, we can't answer it.

Comment: @AliceD How about: What's the neural correlate of the effects I perceive while making these optical illusion pictures move?

Comment: Imo the second example is entirely different and #1 and #3 may also be separate effects. Too broad imo as  it's not based on a solid premise.

Comment: I don't perceive any illusion when moving it, just curved lines

Comment: @AliceD Can't you see the whole stretching and contracting, somewhat like a pumping heart? Maybe you should isolate the figure and move it to and fro horizontally. The curved lines (which are actually straight) are also visible when you don't move the picture, but these curved lines start to wave if you move the picture. Somehow the volumes of the small squares change. And so the volume of the whole picture.